# Degraded performance in boot after installing the Gnome Desktop

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 via a minimal CD. it looked like a terminal window so I did: apt-get install gnome and it downloaded a lot of stuff. Then I rebooted and created an account.

It's been taking Ubuntu a lot time to boot, I get a purple screen with four dots and they light up and unlight and then it says trying to make network connections. then wait up to 60 seconds for network connections and then finally it loads but it takes what it seems like 10 minutes.

I don't know much about Ubuntu or Linux and I don't know what to do. Below is my `dmesg.txt`

```
[   13.678111] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000001028-0x000000000000102f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.LPC_.PMIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)  
[   13.678117] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver  
[   13.678121] ACPI Warning: 0x00000000000011c0-0x00000000000011cf SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.LPC_.LPIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)  
[   13.678124] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver  
[   13.678126] ACPI Warning: 0x00000000000011b0-0x00000000000011bf SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.LPC_.LPIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)  
[   13.678129] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver  
[   13.678131] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000001180-0x00000000000011af SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.LPC_.LPIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)  
[   13.678134] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver  
[   13.678135] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich  
[   13.678163] intel ips 0000:00:1f.6: CPU TDP doesn't match expected value (found 25, expected 29)  
[   13.681046] intel ips 0000:00:1f.6: IPS driver initialized, MCP temp limit 90  
[   14.005261] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro  
[   14.816628] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3  
[   14.816633] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast  
[   14.816645] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized  
[   14.819962] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized  
[   14.819972] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized  
[   14.819989] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11  
[   14.876241] init: cups main process (679) killed by HUP signal  
[   14.876251] init: cups main process ended, respawning  
[   44.656633] audit_printk_skb: 15 callbacks suppressed  
[   44.656637] type=1400 audit(1411842253.358:17): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=772 comm="apparmor_parser"  
[   44.656642] type=1400 audit(1411842253.358:18): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=772 comm="apparmor_parser"  
[   44.656974] type=1400 audit(1411842253.358:19): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=772 comm="apparmor_parser"  
[   45.197990] type=1400 audit(1411842253.902:20): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=783 comm="apparmor_parser"  
[  134.371056] type=1400 audit(1411842343.066:21): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=845 comm="apparmor_parser"  
[  134.371068] type=1400 audit(1411842343.066:22): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=845 comm="apparmor_parser"  
[  134.371075] type=1400 audit(1411842343.066:23): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=845 comm="apparmor_parser"  
[  134.371634] type=1400 audit(1411842343.066:24): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=845 comm="apparmor_parser"  
[  134.371642] type=1400 audit(1411842343.066:25): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=845 comm="apparmor_parser"  
[  134.371939] type=1400 audit(1411842343.066:26): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=845 comm="apparmor_parser"  
[  134.372867] type=1400 audit(1411842343.066:27): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=848 comm="apparmor_parser"  
[  134.372877] type=1400 audit(1411842343.066:28): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*" pid=848 comm="apparmor_parser"  
[  134.372882] type=1400 audit(1411842343.066:29): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="pxgsettings" pid=848 comm="apparmor_parser"  
[  134.372887] type=1400 audit(1411842343.066:30): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="sanitized_helper" pid=848 comm="apparmor_parser"  
[  135.881872] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning  
[  140.632349] audit_printk_skb: 111 callbacks suppressed  
[  140.632353] type=1400 audit(1411842349.326:68): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mkdir" profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/var/lib/gdm/.config/libaccounts-glib/" pid=1256 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=109 ouid=109  
[  140.633730] type=1400 audit(1411842349.326:69): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/etc/dconf/profile/gdm" pid=1256 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=109 ouid=0  
[  279.680163] systemd-hostnamed[2366]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!  
[  315.510567] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S  
[  315.517211] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x3-0x1  
[  315.730221] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S  
[  315.736867] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x3-0x1  
[  315.845725] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready  
[  315.846186] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready  
[  324.910415] wlan0: authenticate with 08:86:3b:3f:7e:84  
[  324.950872] wlan0: No basic rates, using min rate instead  
[  324.951752] wlan0: send auth to 08:86:3b:3f:7e:84 (try 1/3)  
[  325.015646] wlan0: authenticated  
[  325.017197] wlan0: associate with 08:86:3b:3f:7e:84 (try 1/3)  
[  325.018258] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 08:86:3b:3f:7e:84 (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=1)  
[  325.021212] wlan0: associated  
[  325.021258] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready  
[  326.924456] IPv6: wlan0: IPv6 duplicate address fe80::5a94:6bff:fe22:3680 detected!  
[  859.626104] wlan0: deauthenticating from 08:86:3b:3f:7e:84 by local choice (reason=3)  
[  859.689458] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain  
[  859.692213] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:  
[  859.692216] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)  
[  859.692217] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  859.692219] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  859.692220] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  859.692221] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  859.692222] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  861.227447] type=1400 audit(1411843069.583:70): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mkdir" profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/var/lib/gdm/.config/libaccounts-glib/" pid=3042 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=109 ouid=109  
[  861.229323] type=1400 audit(1411843069.587:71): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/etc/dconf/profile/gdm" pid=3042 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=109 ouid=0  
[  907.414223] systemd-hostnamed[4099]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!  
[  914.489960] wlan0: authenticate with 08:86:3b:3f:7e:84  
[  914.501260] wlan0: No basic rates, using min rate instead  
[  914.501893] wlan0: send auth to 08:86:3b:3f:7e:84 (try 1/3)  
[  914.697288] wlan0: authenticated  
[  914.699554] wlan0: associate with 08:86:3b:3f:7e:84 (try 1/3)  
[  914.700502] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 08:86:3b:3f:7e:84 (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=1)  
[  914.703336] wlan0: associated  
[  915.828027] IPv6: wlan0: IPv6 duplicate address fe80::5a94:6bff:fe22:3680 detected!  
[ 1498.108127] perf samples too long (2515 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I see in the output you posted is this:
`IPv6: wlan0: IPv6 duplicate address fe80::5a94:6bff:fe22:3680 detected!`
which theoretically shouldn't happen, since ipv6 addresses use theoretically unique mac addresses as part of the address structure.  So, somehow, you've been the subject of a statistical anomaly whether it be crafted or accidental.

Either way, network interfaces stalling will cause boot to stall until a much longer than normal timeout passes and boot resumes.